# How to display a video behind other components?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am creating software in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo using FMX. I want to show a video in the background behind all components using `TMediaPlayerControl`. I send the `TMediaPlayerControl` to the back and play the video, but the video doesn't play behind the components, but rather it plays on top of them.

I put a `TMemo` in the  client area and a `TMediaPlayerControl` behind it. What it should do is play the video behind the `TMemo`, but instead it plays on top of the `TMemo`.

How can I play video in the background behind the `TMemo`?

Comment: This is unclear to me. Perhaps you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Most likely, the media player is using technology that renders the video output directly to the screen, not onto a window. That would explain why it appears on top of everything.

Comment: I've seen uses of TMediaPlayerControl in background then TEdit and TButton and TPanel on top of. I don't remember​ but I saw uses in an application.

Comment: @Abhishek are you sure it was `TMediaPlayerControl` specifically, or just video in general? It makes a difference

Comment: The implementation for TMediaPlayerControl for most of the OS's (likely all of them), use native controls in order to display the video, and there's no Z-order management for it, so they will appear over the top of everything else. Why you'd want a memo to appear over the actual video is beyond me, since it would obscure the picture; I'd put it on one side.

Comment: @Remy Lebeuu I'm not sure about TMediaPlayerControl. It maybe other that I don't know.  Dave Nottage: an video looks great behind an TMemo if you use jet stylebook. I can make it on side but it will look more attractive in background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you will need a video player that can render directly on the openGL surface (ie render on the delphi form actually). As far as i know their is only one videoplayer that can do this, it's the `TalVideoPlayer` implemented in **alcinoe** (https://sourceforge.net/projects/alcinoe/). The current implementation is only for ios / android but the windows implementation seam quite simple to do and the macos version quite trivial as it's use the same api as ios

Comment: In the three years since this post, has a windows-ready video player that renders directly to the Delphi form become available? The use case for me is adding layers for animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the libvlc to render directly to a form or whatever you want.
Call libvlc_media_player_set_display_window() to set a window handle where the media player should render its video output.
So you can show a video in the background behind all components.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using wrapper classes and components from
http://prog.olsztyn.pl/paslibvlc
very simple indeed

Checked in FMX Delphi 10.4.2 - worked properly (libVLC 3.014 - latest)